# No carga archivos JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema: me encuentro realizando un curso de MVC con PHP, AJAX, JavaScript, etc... Todo funciona correctamente, pero me esta dando un dolor de cabeza al momento de que no se encuentra cargando los archivos JavaScript en donde los estoy llamando. He verificado algunas posibilidades, al entrar a la carpeta en el DevTools y veo que no se encuentra la carpeta *"js"* dentro de dicho listado.

[Adjunto Imagen]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo la estructura de mis carpetas desde el IDE vscode
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no he encontrado el problema a lo que puede ser. Voy a dejar el código de los archivos, de cómo tengo controlador, archivo template e index

**index.php**

```
<?php

// Controladores
// ───  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//

require_once "controllers/template.controller.php";
require_once "controllers/categorias.controller.php";
require_once "controllers/clientes.controller.php";
require_once "controllers/productos.controller.php";
require_once "controllers/usuarios.controller.php";
require_once "controllers/ventas.controller.php";


// Modelos
// ───  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
//

require_once "models/categorias.model.php";
require_once "models/clientes.model.php";
require_once "models/productos.model.php";
require_once "models/usuarios.model.php";
require_once "models/ventas.model.php";

$plantilla = new PlantillaCtrl();
$plantilla->ctrlPlantilla();
```

**views/template.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Inventory System</title>


    <!--=================================
    =            Estilos CSS            =
    =====================================-->

    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="icon" href="views/img/plantilla/icono-negro.png">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/dist/css/AdminLTE.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.css">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">

    <!--=====  End of Estilos CSS  ======-->

    <!--=================================
    =            JavaScript             =
    =====================================-->

    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="views/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <script src="views/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="views/bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="views/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script src="views/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="views/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="views/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="views/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- SweetAlert JS -->
    <script src="views/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <!--=====  End of Javascript   ======-->
</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-collapse sidebar-mini login-page">

        <?php

            if (isset($_SESSION["iniciarSesion"]) && $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"] == "ok")
            {
                echo '<div class="wrapper">';

                /*----------  Cabecera  ----------*/
                include "modules/cabezote.php";
                /*----------  Menú  ----------*/
                include "modules/menu.php";
                /*----------  Contenido  ----------*/
                if (isset($_GET["ruta"]))
                {
                    if ($_GET["ruta"] == "inicio" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "usuarios" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "categorias" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "productos" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "clientes" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "ventas" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "crear-venta" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "reportes" || 
                        $_GET["ruta"] == "salir")
                    {
                        include "modules/". $_GET["ruta"] .".php";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        include "modules/404.php";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    include "modules/inicio.php";
                }
                /*----------  Pie de Página  ----------*/
                include "modules/footer.php";

                echo '</div>';
            }
            else
            {
                include "modules/login.php";
            }
        ?>

    <!-- Scripts que no cargan al momento de cargar la plantilla -->
    <script src="views/js/plantilla.js"></script>
    <script src="views/js/usuarios.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**controllers/template.controller.php**

```
<?php

    class PlantillaCtrl {
        static public function ctrlPlantilla()
        {
            include "views/template.php";
        }
    }
```

No he encontrado la causa raíz acerca de esto. En los archivos js lo que estoy realizando, es cargar una función de la plantilla AdminLTE y DataTables para la tabla dinámica, en conjunto con su traducción.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la ruta completa ejemplo creas una constante dentro de Index.php

```
   //Aqui pones el nombre de tu carpeta  creo que es POS
    const SERVERURL ="http://localhost/POS/";
```

Y  los js lo cargas así

```
    <script src="<?php echo SERVERURL;?>views/js/plantilla.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Ya realice la prueba quitando el index y no me carga los archivos, sigue en lo mismo ....

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tendrias que quitar la raiz `views` de las llamadas ya que llamas los archivos desde `views/template.php`. Te quedaria algo asi: `<script src="js/plantilla.js"></script>`

Comment: Ya realice la prueba quitando el index y no me carga los archivos, sigue en lo mismo ....

Comment: El error concretamente cual es?

Comment: Cuando entro a la página del proyecto, tengo unos archivos, js ubicados en views/js/<archivos>, no me los esta cargando, parece que la carpeta no se encuentra creada ni mucho menos los archivos. No se cuál sea la razón por la cual aparecen. Eh indagado [Como lo mencione en la pregunta], pero no encuentro una razón lógica por el cual ya no aparecen y al verificar en la carpeta, se encuentran los archivos correspondientes, la función de AdminLTE, DataTables [Traducido al Español], validaciones de imágenes, ajax, pero, no detecta el sistema esto ...

Comment: entiendo que solo te cargan mal los js? los .css cargan correctamente? Habre la consola del navegador y mira que error te da